# Small circles on sphere: finding angles for constant "cosine" onto a parallel.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

My problem can be best explained starting from a 2D example:

Imagine having a circle and wanting to discretize N points on the circumference of the circle so that the difference of the cosine of each pair of adjacent points is constant.

This is relatively easy, as it would be sufficient to discretize the diameter of the unit circle, and then apply $acos()$ to each cosine sample.

What I have been unsuccessfully looking for is a solution for the transposition of this problem onto a small circle on a sphere.
To visualize it, imagine we are talking about the **Another Small Circle** setup in the image below (the right one).
And let's assume, unlike the illustration, that the small circle that has been cut away does not contain the pole (although it might make no difference).

[image]
<sub>(source: [slideplayer.com](http://images.slideplayer.com/27/9119414/slides/slide_6.jpg))</sub>

What i'm looking for is a discretization of the circumference of this small circle so that the delta (or difference) of the projection of each pair of adjacent samples onto the parallel going through the center of the small circle is constant.
The projection of each sample onto the parallel (of latitude) is done by a meridian (that is a great circle going through the poles and the sample on the parallel)

Comment: Wait, let me get this right. You have the parallel (of latitude), call it $C$, that passes through the center of your small circle $S$. And you are mapping from $S$ to $C$ by taking a point $s\in S$ and drawing a great circle $\Sigma$ through $s$ that hits $C$ orthogonally at $f(s)\in C\,$? And you want the points $f(s_i)$ to be equally spaced on $C$?

Comment: You are right, i forgot to explain one detail, i will modify my question.
Actually the mapping onto the parallel should be done by a meridian, that is a great circle going through the poles and the point on the parallel of latitude.
Thanks for the question!

Comment: This actually made me realize my question was ill-asked, and maybe a reason for not figuring out the solution.

Perhaps the solution could be the following steps?
1) discretizing the parallel segment bounded by the small circle.
2) for each sample, finding the meridian going through that point.
3) for each of these meridians, find the (2) points on the small circle it intersects

Comment: I think that what you really want to do, once you get a clear picture of the map $S\to C$, is to consider instead its (presumably multi-valued) inverse, from $C$ to $S$, and start with your evenly-spaced points on $C$ and see where they go on $S$.